# Данные из data при вводе в input не выводятся

Tags: vue.js

Указываю в инпут "1" - данные выводятся. Указываю "first" либо другие - ничего не выводится, а должно выводиться. Как исправить?

```js
new Vue({
  el: ".app",
  data: {
    names: {
       first: 'Boris',
       second: 'Alex',
       third: 'Mary',
       1: 'Leslie'
    },
    message: ""
  },
  computed: {
    translated() {
      return this.message.split('').map(item => {
          return this.names[item] || '';
      }).join('');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
p {
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <div class="app">
    
    <input type="text" v-model="message" />
    <p id="text">Текст : {{ message }}</p>
    <p>{{ translated }}</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте простой возврат, или их может быть несколько ?

```js
new Vue({
  el: ".app",
  data: {
    names: {
       first: 'Boris',
       second: 'Alex',
       third: 'Mary',
       1: 'Leslie'
    },
    message: ""
  },
  computed: {
    translated() {
      return this.names[this.message];
      //return this.message.split('').map(item => {
      //    return this.names[item] || '';
      //}).join('');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  //height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <div class="app">
    
    <input type="text" v-model="message" />
    <p id="text">Текст : {{ message }}</p>
    <p>{{ translated }}</p>
 </div>
```